# Spring Security SessionRegistry with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: spring-security

My application's sequrity system is based on Spring Sequrity 3.1. I am using PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.

I need to display a list of all logged users using Sessionregistrympl. The problem is that when the site goes "rememberme-user", it's session does not exist in SessionRegistry.

My configuration files:web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
```

and spring-sequrity.xml:

```
<s:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" > 

    <s:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter"/>
    <s:custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" ref="rememberMeFilter" />
    <s:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref= "concurrencyFilter" />           
    <s:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter" />

    <s:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**/" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>     
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/**/" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_GUEST"/>        
    <s:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />

</s:http>



<bean 
  id="logoutFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"
  p:filterProcessesUrl="/logout/">
  <constructor-arg value="/login/" />
    <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="rememberMeServices" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" p:invalidateHttpSession="true"/>
    </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:loginFormUrl="/login/"/>


<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    p:defaultTargetUrl="/index/" />


<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:defaultFailureUrl="/login/error/" />


<bean id="rememberMeServices" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices"
    p:tokenRepository-ref="jdbcTokenRepository"
    p:userDetailsService-ref="hibernateUserService"
    p:key="pokeristStore"
    p:tokenValiditySeconds="1209600" />

<bean id="jdbcTokenRepository" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
    p:key="pokeristStore" />

<bean id="rememberMeFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="rememberMeServices"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager" />


<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager"
    p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="rememberMeServices"
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<bean id="sas"      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"
    p:maximumSessions="1">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="concurrencyFilter" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"
    p:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry" />


<bean id="sessionRegistry" 
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />


<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="256"/>
</bean>

<bean id="saltSource"  
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">  
    <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateUserService"
    class="com.mysite.service.simple.SecurityUserDetailsService"/>


<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">    
     <s:authentication-provider user-service-ref="hibernateUserService">            
        <s:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <s:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </s:password-encoder>   
    </s:authentication-provider>
    <s:authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

One of the solutions found by me - is to set alwaysReauthenticate property to 'true' in  FilterSecurityInterceptor bean, but it affects the performance of web-site.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`, to populate the session registry. This is described in the [session management](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions) section of the manual. Check out the configuration example in there if you want to use plain Spring beans. Note that you need to inject it into both the supply the same reference to both the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and the `session-management` namespace element.

Comment: I have not been able to get sessionregistry to work with rememberMe and https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2028 states that this issue is still open. Who's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `SessionRegistry` to be populated Spring Security have to create a session, try adding `create-session="always"` to your `<http>` tag in Spring Security configuration file.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be necessary, and will result in sessions being created unnecessarily.